# Cmake - Differentiating symbols among targets

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake, target, symbols

In CMake for Visual Studio 10, C++ language, I need to set some symbols (added through the add_definitions command) only for the add_library target (which is creating a .dll) and I want to avoid the same symbols to be defined for the add_executable target which generate the testing applications for the library defined as target by add_library.
How can I do that? Now the symbols appear to be defined for the projects of the library and of the tests...

Answer (score 3):

When you want to specify defines for an individual target, use [target_compile_definitions](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:target_compile_definitions)

Comment: Keep in mind, this requires CMake 3.x. In CMake 2.x, there is no way to separate the definitions by target. They are always assigned to all targets in that project (not sure, whether they are inherited by subprojects).

Comment: The link to the documentation is from CMake 2.8.12. Even before it was possible with COMPILE_DEFINITIONS (target property)

Comment: I stand corrected. Thank you :) I just checked, `target_compile_definitions` was indeed added in CMake 2.8.11